# XML can't be validated against the local XML schema file

Tags: xml

I have a very simple XML file and a XML schema file. I have been trying to validate the XML file against the schema to no avail. Here are the details;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <xsd:element name="StockDataSet">
  <xsd:complexType>
   <xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element name="StockRecord" maxOccurs="unbounded">
     <xsd:complexType>
      <!--<xsd:sequence>-->
       <xsd:element name="Item_Code" type="xsd:string" />
       <xsd:element name="Item_Description" type="xsd:string" />
       <xsd:element name="Current_Count" type="xsd:positiveInteger" />
       <xsd:element name="On_Order">
        <xsd:simpleType>
         <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
          <xsd:enumeration value="yes" />
          <xsd:enumeration value="Yes" />
          <xsd:enumeration value="YES" />
          <xsd:enumeration value="no" />
          <xsd:enumeration value="No" />
          <xsd:enumeration value="NO" />
         </xsd:restriction>
        </xsd:simpleType>
       </xsd:element>
      </xsd:sequence>
     </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
   </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
 </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<StockDataSet xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org./2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="stockschema.xsd" >
  <StockRecord>
    <Item_Code>A0001</Item_Code>
    <Item_Description>Horse on Wheels</Item_Description>
    <Current_Count>5</Current_Count>
    <On_Order>Yes</On_Order>
  </StockRecord>
  <StockRecord>
    <Item_Code>A0002</Item_Code>
    <Item_Description>Elephant on Wheels</Item_Description>
    <Current_Count>2</Current_Count>
    <On_Order>No</On_Order>
  </StockRecord>
  <StockRecord>
    <Item_Code>A0003</Item_Code>
    <Item_Description>Dog on Wheels</Item_Description>
    <Current_Count>23</Current_Count>
    <On_Order>Yes</On_Order>
  </StockRecord>
</StockDataSet>
```

Now I used the Apatan studio and it was giving a vague error. I also used the [xml_validation_online] and the error is  *cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation' is not allowed to appear in element 'StockDataSet'.*

[xml_validation_online] http://www.xmlvalidation.com/

Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Omg, I found the culprit.

StockDataSet xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org./2001

Extra dot after org caused the problem. Embarrassig, spent hours! Thanks anyway